# Android: get activity from tab or intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

my app uses a tab bar, each tab button associates an Activity, so when you click on a tab button, it shows the screen for that activity, now it need to detect user click on current/active tab button, I've already finished the code to detect that, but now I need to inform the corresponding activity of the click, is there any way to get the activity associated with tab button? Or can I get the activity started by an intent, if I have the reference to the intent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little late for your answer but you can try :

```
String tabTag = getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag(); 
Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag);
```